# Twilio number that is connected to Twilio Studio Application is failing with Error - 11200

Tags: twilio

I have a Twilio number that is connected to a Twilio studio application. Everything was fine until this morning. Every time I call the number I get "we are sorry an application error has occured"

here is my log 
An attempt to retrieve content from https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts//Flows/ returned the HTTP status code 400

Answer (score 0):

it is really difficult to say what the issue is without Studio logs. You can look at your Twilio Studio logs which may provide more insight behind the error. The link to the logs are on the left side of the screen when you are view your Studio Flow canvas.

If that doesn't help, then next step would to open a ticket with Twilio via the console or help@twilio.com with the details of your Studio Flow and the Studio Execution SID (important), so they can further investigate the root cause.

Alan